# Report viewer hangs silently after closing with the X

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, memory, printing

**Update** it seems like the app doesn't know when the print task has finished, and keeps the connection open indefinitely. is there a way to kill this connection?

when i debug a wpf with a report viewer and i print a document, i can't seem to fully close the wpf.

i press the X on the window and the window closes, but vs keeps running. Pausing doesn't show where it stays hanging though and there aren't any threads in the wpf.

we overwrote the printing to skip the dialog, but trying to set everything to null after it runs doesn't help. Any ideas why it keeps hanging? (closing the app before it prints works fine.)

These three threads are still working, is there a way to find out why they stay open?

Unflagged       1424    7   Worker Thread   vshost.RunParkingWindow [Managed to Native Transition]  Normal

Unflagged       4320    8   Worker Thread   .NET SystemEvents   [Managed to Native Transition]  Normal

Unflagged   >   4332    9   Main Thread Main Thread [Managed to Native Transition]  Normal

```
        protected override void OnPrintCommand()
    {
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        printDialog.PrintQueue = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue();
        printDialog.PrintTicket = printDialog.PrintQueue.DefaultPrintTicket;

        FixedDocument fixedDocument = this.Document as FixedDocument;               
        FixedDocumentSequence fixedDocumentSequence = this.Document as FixedDocumentSequence;               
        if (fixedDocument != null) fixedDocument.PrintTicket = printDialog.PrintTicket;               
        if (fixedDocumentSequence!= null) fixedDocumentSequence.PrintTicket = printDialog.PrintTicket;               

        XpsDocumentWriter writer = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(printDialog.PrintQueue);              
        if (fixedDocument != null) writer.WriteAsync(fixedDocument, printDialog.PrintTicket);               
        if (fixedDocumentSequence != null) writer.WriteAsync(fixedDocumentSequence, printDialog.PrintTicket);

        printDialog = null;
        fixedDocument = null;
        fixedDocumentSequence = null;
        writer = null;
    }
```

Comment: Use Debug + Break All, Debug + Windows + Threads and find out what the threads you see there are doing.

Comment: You might have some lingering thread that is not set as a background thread that is keeping the process execution alive, if you have any custom threading I would look there using Hans technique.

Comment: i have checked the threads. there are three still running, i updated the questions, but i don't create any threads myself, so i'm not sure how i can find out what i can do about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the extension suppressed the document viewer from popping up, the report stayed active in the background.

the solution was simple, not to suppress the viewer, print the document and then close the viewer. Optionally you could also hide the viewer before closing it.

The app closes itself after this fix.

Answer (score 1):

Does it do the same when you run it without debugging? You call writer.WriteAsync(), is it possible it is still writing when you try to close the application?

You should probably wireup an event for the completion of the writeasync method. See the link for a pretty good example of using XpsDocumentWriter with a WritingCompleted callback.

[WPF Recipes](http://books.google.com/books?id=clLc5BBHqRMC&pg=PA398&lpg=PA398&dq=XpsDocumentWriter.writeasync&source=bl&ots=_r7ht1OAiM&sig=omu0MthWBvT7dmIgXzZiOyHe7bw&hl=en&ei=cGJ6TcvJJcLyrAGY6ITtBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=9&ved=0CFIQ6AEwCA)